# How many games did Romero and Carmack create before Doom?

Tags: gaming-history, doom

Both Romero and Carmack created many games and sold them to computer magazines in the 80s as their initial foray making games.

I think I remember a line in Master of Doom that they had both created 80-90 games by themselves each before they started working together, and maybe Romero even mentioned specifically which number Doom was for him. But I no longer have the book

Answer (score 1):

For Romero, has a quote saying "at least 60" before working at id Software in an interview:

> id Software was my fourth startup company and I’d made at least 60 games before it...

[Source](https://www.loudersound.com/features/my-whole-life-has-been-heavy-metal-doom-creator-john-romero-on-making-the-most-notorious-game-of-all-time)